# Error load KML in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, location, kml

I have installed Android Studio 2.2 and I try to use the location option to set up a location. I want to do it through a KML file but always I receive the same error:

[image]

The file that I use to load the location is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.x">
    <Placemark>
        <name>Casa de ACME</name>
        <description>Casa de ACME</description>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-1.705219,38.267902,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
</kml>
```

What is wrong in my file? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried your file and it loaded correctly (on my machine). Most probably this means the issue is machine-specific. Looking at the code, I see the following very config-dependent block:

```
GpsFix new_fix;
while(3 == sscanf(coordinates + offset,
                  "%f , %f , %f%n",
                  &new_fix.longitude,
                  &new_fix.latitude,
                  &new_fix.elevation,
                  &n)) {
    fixes->push_back(new_fix);
    offset += n;
}
```

This code doesn't work if the decimal separator is set to anything but '.' on your machine.

Emulator bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=224400

Comment: So ... I guess that I have to change the language from spanish to english ... I'll try ... Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: Hi MT-Wizard!!! Finally, I have change in Ubuntu my format of dates, numbers, etc. to "English (United States)" and it works!!! With my original configuration "Spanish (Spain)" doesn't work.